# Out of memory when processing multiple large bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

In the app I'm working on, part of the user's input is a series of images. Some of these might be 4MB large in their raw form. I resize and rotate them, then save them in the app's portion of the device memory for later use. The problem I'm experiencing is that I seem to run out of memory even though I recycle each Bitmap after it's saved.

Here's the main processing

```
private class SaveImagesTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Long... ids){
        long id = ids[0];
        Iterator<ImageButton> itImg = arrBtnImage.iterator();
        Iterator<TextView> itLbl = arrLblImage.iterator();
        while(itImg.hasNext() && itLbl.hasNext()){
            String imgPath = (String) itImg.next().getTag();
            String imgLbl = itLbl.next().getText().toString().trim();
            String imgName = imgLbl.replace(" ", "_").replace(",", "_");
            imgName += ".jpg";

            if(imgPath != null){
                /* Save resized version of image */
                File dir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
                dir = new File(dir, "temp/" + Long.toString(plantId));
                boolean madeDir = dir.mkdirs();
                File path = new File(dir, imgName);
                Bitmap toSave = getScaledBitmap(imgPath, IMAGE_MAX_SIDE_LENGTH, IMAGE_MAX_SIDE_LENGTH);

                try{
                    BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
                    boolean insertSuccess = toSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream);
                    outStream.close();
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                toSave.recycle();
            }//if
        }//while(more images to process)
    }// method: doInBackground(params)
}// inner class: saveImages extends AsyncTask
```

And here's where I resize the image

```
private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(String picturePath, int newWidth, int newHeight){
    /* Size */
    BitmapFactory.Options sizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);
    int sampleSize = 1;
    int rawHeight = sizeOptions.outHeight;
    int rawWidth = sizeOptions.outWidth;
    if(rawHeight > newHeight || rawWidth > newWidth){
        /* Find the dimension that needs to change the most */
        int heightRatio = Math.round((float) rawHeight / (float) newHeight);
        int widthRatio = Math.round((float) rawWidth / (float) newWidth);

        sampleSize = (heightRatio > widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio);
    }//if(raw image is wider or taller than it should be){reduce size so neither is too large}

    sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;//Load pixels for display.
    sizeOptions.inSampleSize = sampleSize;//Set shrink factor.
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);

    /* Rotation */
    int rotation = 1;
    try{
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(picturePath);
        rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int rotationInDegrees = 0;
    if(rotation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90)
        rotationInDegrees = 90;
    else if(rotation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)
        rotationInDegrees = 180;
    else if(rotation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270)
        rotationInDegrees = 270;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    if(rotation != 0f)
        matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, 
                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}// method: getScaledBitmap(String, int, int)
```

Before I start getting comments about this being so common of a question, I'll point out that I'm not displaying these images, so it's not like I'm trying to keep all of these in memory. I need to keep large images because users will want to be able to zoom in on the pictures, but I'm resizing them because they don't need to be ridiculously huge. Pretty much any other solution I've seen on SO for images and OOM errors don't apply to my back-to-back access of multiple images.

So like I said, I'm recycling each Bitmap after it's saved, but they still seem to be using memory. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you read through this? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Like I said, I'm not displaying them, nor can I resize them to only a few hundred pixels. But yes, I did read it. It's quite handy for some of the other stuff I'm doing, but not this.

Answer (score 1):

You're not recycling `scaledBitmap` in `getScaledBitmap`. Fixing that should help. Change this line:

```
return Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, 
            scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

to something like:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, 
            scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
scaledBitmap.recycle();
return newBitmap;
```

Comment: Wouldn't the GC get that? Could the app be somehow moving too fast for the GC to catch it?

Comment: Eventually. If you're cycling through many bitmaps quickly though, sometimes it helps to mark bitmaps for recycle as early as possible. Technically the same argument on both sides applies to your original use of recycle.

Comment: It was worth a shot, but it turns out that `newBitmap` seems to retain a reference to `scaledBitmap`. I got an error saying, "Can't compress a recycled bitmap." The documentation does state that the original Object might be returned, but I wouldn't think that would be the case here, because of the rotation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple threads working on large bitmaps, you will use a lot of memory on some cases.

What you need is to find the best approach according to your needs. here are some things you can do and/or need to know:

1. use a single thread for the images handling.
2. always recycle old bitmaps that you don't need anymore, as soon as possible. it's true that the GC will help you, but that can help it too, and it will work even on pre-honeycomb devices.
3. do the image manipulations via NDK (so you won't need to have 2 bitmaps for each image manipulation), for example using [**this**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations).
4. downsample the image to the minimal size that you need, and never assume that the memory is large enough for any given image (unless you are 100% sure that the images are small).
5. remember that the requirements for android devices are still very low in terms of RAM per app (heap size) - the bare minimal is still 16MB per app.
6. you can use android:largeHeap="true" in the manifest, but that doesn't mean anything about how much more you will get, if at all.

Comment: My work on this app mostly stopped at the end of the summer, and my effort has been refocused toward a corresponding website. In the meantime I settled for just downsizing the images. Hopefully someone else will be hired to continue my work on the app this coming summer. I'll make sure the next guy knows about your answer with NDK, and hopefully he'll be able to incorporate it (and your other suggestions). Thank you for the answer though! It looks promising.

Comment: @Stspurg yes. i also searched for a nice way to do the decoding on the "jni world" ( C/C++) , but i couldn't find any, so what i've done is letting it get what the "java world" has, then I recycle the bitmap and do the work on the "jni world", and after I'm done, I return the result bitmap to the "java world".